# What are Redis timeseries module restrictions

Tags: redis, time-series

I didn't find it in any official document, what is redis timeseries module's restrictions in terms of the following:

1. Max number of labels which can be added?
2. Max size of keys?
3. Max number of keys or time series?

Please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Max number of labels which can be added?

A. There is no hard limit but you might experience some performance degradation when querying a  very large number of labels.

> 2. Max size of keys?

A. There is no limit as long as you have memory available for the module. It is recommended to downsample your data and retire raw data by using the RETENTION option. Data compression was recently added to the module which reduces memory footprint significantly.

> 3. Max number of keys or time series?

A. There is no limit beyond the usual limits on Redis itself.